# How to make table data elements take up only as much space as they need?

Tags: html, css, kendo-ui

I'm working on a webpage for our application but I am not a designer / front end UI developer in any sense of the word.

I've got 2 divs floating next to each other, each div contains a table with some data to be entered by the user. I was having issues with the drop down menus in the `<TD>` elements being cut off, so I changed it from `<table>` to `<table border="1" style="color: orange;">` but this made the text in the table orange; my mistake.

[image]

But that's what it looks like. The table on the right, in black, looks good. Everything's aligned nice and even. The table on the left, in orange, is not good. For some reason the (i) icons are taking up way too much space and are pushing my drop down menu `<td>`'s over, cutting them off.

Then I went back to the code and changed it t `style="border-color: orange;"` so I could get an easier look differentiaiting the table borders from the input controls and such. And that's when it gets *really* screwy:

[image]

As you can see, nothing is orange now. Not the text, no the border. But more interesting: the controls (created with Telerik's Kendo UI) are text boxes and not drop downs, and they take up their own width in the cell. More interestingly, this even changed the controls in the **other** div / table.

So, anyways, the question is, what can I do to make these (i) icons only take up as much space as they need? I've tried simply adding `width="25px"` to the `TD` elements but cell containing my controls is still scrunched :(

The left table looks like:

```
<div style="width:100%">
    <div style="width: 40%; float: left">
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5">Some Text</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5">Section B - Other Text</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>BB0700.&nbsp;</td>
                <td>More Text</td>
                <td class="textalign-right">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="textalign-center">
                    @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(modelObject => modelObject.FieldName).HtmlAttributes(new { id = "cmbFieldName", @class = "width-85" })) 
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img src="..\..\..\..\UDSMR.UDSCentral.Web\Content\images\Icons\info_Desc.gif" />
                </td>
            </tr>
```

And the right table is more or less defined the same, just with a different number of columns.

Answer (score -1):

Step 1 - style="border: 1px solid orange;"

Step 2 - Guessing a bit here, but looks like the icons in left table are in cells with a border - in right table they seem not to be. This would effect layout.

But I know nothing of Kendo so it could be to do with that??

Comment: Ah, I forgot to mention that yes, on the right-hand table the icons are in the same table data element as the control. There was no alignment problems with that table, so I didn't seem to need to throw them out into their own cell, since the icon exists on every row. It doesn't exist for every row on the left hand table though, so I needed to put them in their own